# How to show that $|G|=d_1^2+\cdots +d_s^2$ and $G$ is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, p-groups, representation-of-algebras

In *Representation Theory of Finite Groups: An Introductory Approach* by Benjamin Steinberg, there is a corollary in which I feel confused.

> Corollary 6.2.6. *Let p be a prime and let $G$ be a group of order
> $p^2$. Then $G$ is abelian.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $d_1, \cdots,d_s$ be the degrees of the irreducible representations of $G$. Then $d_i$ can be $1$, $p$ or $p^2$. Since the
> trivial representation has degree $1$ and
> $$p^2=|G|=d_1^2+\cdots+d_s^2$$ it follows that all $d_i=1$ and hence
> $G$ is abelian.

I have two questions:

1. Why does the equation $p^2=|G|=d_1^2+\cdots+d_s^2$ hold?
2. Why is $G$ abelian if each of its irreducible representations has the degree $d_i=1$?

I have not yet found any theory before Corollary 6.2.6 in this book to illustrate these questions. Could you please give me some hints to show them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any finite group, the sum of the squares of the dimensions of its irreducible representations is the order of the group - i.e. the equation
$$\vert G\vert = d_1^2 + \ldots + d_s^2$$
is true for any finite group, and since $\vert G\vert = p^2$ we get the full equation. This follows from character theory and the orthogonality relations.

For your second question, I'd have a think about the conjugacy classes, and how the number of conjugacy classes of a group is related to the number of irreducible representations - how many irreducible representations does $G$ have if each $d_i=1$?

Let me know if you want any more hints or explanations :)

Comment: Dunno why you got $-1$, I gave $+1$. Also Artin-Wedderburn answers $(1)$ and $(2)$.